# Improve function speed

Tags: javascript, performance, function

I'm doing a BattleShip game in javascript with iio engine.

I'm trying to play against a computer so I have to put a random position for the ships (I hope you know the game :) ).

I have 5 ships that have to be placed in a grid (10x10). The problem is that the function is pretty slow, and sometimes the page don't get load at all.

I want to know if there are some emprovement for the speed of these function, I'm a little bit newbie :D

```
function posShips(size){
    // var size -> size of the ship
    var isOk = false; // flag var to check if the ship is in a right position
    var isOk2 = true; // flag var, become false if the cell is already fill with another ship
    var i; 
    var j;
    var side; // horizontal or vertical
    while(!isOk){
        i = iio.getRandomInt(1,11);
        j = iio.getRandomInt(1,11);
        side = iio.getRandomInt(0,2);
        if((side ? j : i)+size-1 < 11){ // Not out of the array
            for (var k = 0;  k < size; k++) { // Size of the ship
                if(side){
                    if(gridHit[i][j+k].stat == "empty"){ //If is empty put the ship
                        gridHit[i][j+k].stat = "ship";
                        gridHit[i][j+k].setFillStyle("red")
                    }else{ // If not empty
                        isOk2 = false; //Position is not good, do all the thing again.
                        for (var a = 0;  a < size; a++) { // Reset cell
                            gridHit[i][j+a].stat = "empty";
                        }
                        k = 10;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(gridHit[i+k][j].stat == "empty"){ //If is empty put the ship
                        gridHit[i+k][j].stat = "ship";
                        gridHit[i+k][j].setFillStyle("red")
                    }else{ // If not empty
                        isOk2 = false; //Position is not good, do all the thing again.
                        for (var a = 0;  a < size; a++) { // Reset cell
                            gridHit[i+a][j].stat = "empty";
                        }
                        k = 10;
                    }
                }
            };
            if(isOk2)
                isOk = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can read this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/ I think you can use this approach for placing the 5 ships?

Comment: I'd recommend against 'doing it all again'. Perhaps, go through the grid and determine all valid positions, then choose one randomly.

Comment: Is this more fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/performanceemptyloops.htm

Comment: Warning: when clearing up you should go up to `k`, not to `size` otherwise you'd be potentially clearing already placed ships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't pick ship positions that will fall outside the grid.  Pick the direction first, and then limit the `x` and `y` initial positions based on `size`.  e.g. if the size is 3, there's no point going above 7 for the initial value of the varying coordinate.
2. Don't change the array while you're searching.   Do the search first, and only afterwards update the array.  This avoids any "cleanup" operation.
3. Wherever possible, eliminate repeated deep object references.  If accessing `grid[y][x]` repeatedly for differing `x`, take a reference to `grid[y]` first, and then use that for the subsequent accesses.
4. Break out of loops early, there's no point continuing to test a position if a previous one already failed.
5. Place your big ships first - it's easier to fit small ships into the gaps left between the big ones.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Rp9Ke/ for my implementation, with the equivalent of your function being this:

```
this.place = function(size) {

    // faster array access
    var g = this.grid;

    // initial direction, and vector
    var dir = rand(2);  // 0 - y, 1 - x
    var dx = dir ? 1 : 0;
    var dy = dir ? 0 : 1;  // or 1 - dx

    LOOP: while (true) {
        // initial position
        var x = dir ? rand(10 - size) : rand(10);
        var y = dir ? rand(10) : rand(10 - size);

        // test points
        var n = size, tx = x, ty = y;
        while (n--) {
            if (g[ty][tx]) continue LOOP;
            tx += dx;
            ty += dy;
        }

        // fill points
        n = size;
        while (n--) {
            g[y][x] = size;
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }

        break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just perfect, thank you so much :) I found a solution too, without while but recalling the same function and only with 2 for and 2 if :D Thank you again for you suggestion, really useful!